# FORMATO DE LA LISTA

Tags: python, lista

Este código funciona.  Busca en una sublista:

```
dpto = [11, 'a', 'b', 22, [9, 'x', 'xx', 9.9], [8, 'y', 'yy', 8.8], [7, 'z', 'zz', 7.7]]

def buscar(lista, valor):
    for elemento in lista:
        if isinstance(elemento, list):
            if valor == elemento[0]:
                return True
    return False

print (buscar(dpto, 8))
```

Imprime: True.

Me di cuenta que cometo un error con el siguiente código:

```
def agregarSublista(lista, nro, sublis):
    for x in range(len(lista)):
        if (lista[x][0] == nro):
            lista[x][3].append(sublis)
    return lista

def buscarEnSublista(valor, lista):
    esta = False
    for elemento in lista:
        if isinstance(elemento, lista):
            if (valor == elemento[0]):
                esta = True
    return esta

lista = []
print ('CREA UNA LISTA \n')
pos1 = int(input('INGRESE UN NUMERO. - POSICION: \n'))
while  (pos1 != 0):
    pos2 = input('INGRESE TEXTO.: \n')
    pos3 = int(input('INGRESE OTRO NUMERO.: \n'))
    li=[pos1, pos2, pos3,[]]
    lista.append([pos1, pos2, pos3,[]])
    pos1 = int(input('SIGUE?. INGRESE OTRO NUMERO.- POSICION: \n'))
    print ('CARGAR SUBLISTA: \n')
    poslista = int(input('INDICAR LA POSICION DONDE SE AGREGA LA 
    SUBLISTA. \n'))
    otrNro = int(input('CARGA SUBLISTA CON UN NUMERO. \n'))
    while (otrNro != 0):
         otrLet = input('CARGA SUBLISTA CON UNA LETRA. \n')
         otrNumMas = int(input('CARGA SUBLISTA CON UN NUMERO MAS. \n'))
         sublista = [otrNro, otrLet, otrNumMas]
         resu = agregarSublista(lista, poslista, sublista)
         otrNro = int(input('CARGA SUBLISTA CON OTRO NUMERO. \n'))

print ('EL RESULTADO ES: ', resu)
valor = int(input('CONSULTA LA SUBLISTA PARA SABER SI HAY UN 
ELEMENTO: \n'))
ok = buscarEnSublista(valor, resu)
print ('EL VALOR BUSCADO ESTA EN LA SUBLISTA?. \n', ok)
```

No me doy cuenta por qué agrego un corchete más? noten que la primera es [] y esta última es [[]]. entonces me genera este error:

```
if isinstance(elemento, lista):
TypeError: isinstance() arg 2 must be a type or tuple of types
```

Puede ser que este manejando mal la creación de las instancias de la lista que contiene sublistas?
No se si alguien resolvió algo así? gracias.
Pd. por error copie incompleto el código en mi anterior consulta.  Este es el completo.

Comment: El código que pones no produce el resultado que dices. Por favor, pon el código exacto que usas. Procura que el código de la pregunta esté correctamente identado. Así mismo, el error es por usar `lista` como tipo en `isinstance()`, cosa que no veo en el código que has puesto.

Comment: @ChemaCortes. S'i, me equivoque.  Ahora est'a corregido. Mg.

Comment: No tengo claro qué quieres hacer. Intuyo que es una búsqueda anidada a través de las sublistas, pero no veo que hagas ninguna búsqueda recursiva. En cuanto al error, se debe a que usas `lista` en lugar de `list` que es el tipo que hay que emplear en `isintance()`, nada qué ver con el funcionamiento de la búsqueda.